# Error while creating a python binding

Tags: python, c, gcc, binding, shared

This program in C runs and compiles well :

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include <atasmart.h>
int main(){
const char *device = "/dev/sda";
int ret;
 uint64_t ms;
 SkDisk *d;
         if ((ret = sk_disk_open(device, &d)) < 0) {
                        printf("Failed to open disk\n");
                        return 1;
                }





                              if ((ret = sk_disk_smart_read_data(d)) < 0) {
                                printf("Failed to read SMART data: \n");

                        }

                        if ((ret = sk_disk_smart_get_power_on(d, &ms)) < 0) {
                                printf("Failed to get power on time:\n");

                        }

                        printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) ms);


            return 0;

}
```

using:

```
gcc atatest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs libatasmart`
```

However while trying to create python bindings based on that program:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include <atasmart.h>

#include <Python.h>

 static PyObject *pySmart_powerOn(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *device = "/dev/sda";
int ret;
 uint64_t ms;
 SkDisk *d;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &device))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

                        if ((ret = sk_disk_smart_get_power_on(d, &ms)) < 0) {
                              return Py_BuildValue("s", "Failed to get power on time");

                        }
            return Py_BuildValue("K", (unsigned long long) ms);
}

static PyMethodDef pySmart_methods[] = {
        { "powerOn", (PyCFunction)pySmart_powerOn, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
        { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initpySmart()
{
        Py_InitModule3("pySmart", pySmart_methods, "Trial module");
}
```

I create a shared library using

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7 `pkg-config --cflags --libs libatasmart` atabind.c -o pySmart.so -fPIC
```

then I get a warning as follows :, but the file compiles

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from atabind.c:12:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1158:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:214:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

when in Python i run

```
import pySmart
```

I get

```
ImportError: ./pySmart.so: undefined symbol: sk_disk_smart_get_power_on
```

My guess is that the error is caused because I have compiled the pySmart.so shared library with incorrect flags/options.. but I'm unable to figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify linker flags (`-lfoo`) *after* your source files. That's because of the way how linker works: when you specify a library to it, it checks the library for symbols needed so far. If no symbols needed (as if you didn't get to any source objects yet), it just skips the library.

Try the following commandline:

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7 \
     `pkg-config --cflags libatasmart` \
     atabind.c \
     `pkg-config --libs libatasmart` \
     -o pySmart.so -fPIC
```

Comment: And after you get tired of doing this by hand, start using distutils instead: http://docs.python.org/dist

Comment: @ThomasWouters, I do absolutely agree. However, doing things manually sometimes has very good educative properties. `;)`

Comment: Indeed. Hence "after you get tired" :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Will specify source files before everything else.
Was doing it for the first time, hence manually... Do intend to use distutils from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should include your Python.h first then any std header.

All function, type and macro definitions needed to use the Python/C API are included in your code by

`#include "Python.h"`

This implies inclusion of the following standard headers:
 `<stdio.h>, <string.h>, <errno.h>, <limits.h>, <assert.h> and <stdlib.h>` (if available).

Since Python may define some pre-processor definitions which affect the standard headers on some systems, you must include Python.h before any standard headers are included.

**Alternatively:**
just `_GNU_SOURCE` ,  and it will be ignored by GNU libc's /usr/include/features.h